# apolloClient.query not using middleware, while <Query /> does

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I have an apolloclient with middleware that console.logs a bearer token, because I am not always authenticated when I should be.

For some reason, it appears that queries from the react-apollo `<Query />` object use this middleware -- I see my console message -- but queries that I trigger programmatically with: `apolloClient.query` do not log anything (there's no way for the code to do this, the console log is at the top of the authLink middleware).

I started my project with apollo-boost before switching to apolloclient, so I thought perhaps node_modules was not correctly set up after the switch. But I've removed and reinstalled with yarn, it should not have any vestiges of apollo-boost in there now.

**additionally, if I copy the code that I use to create `apolloclient` into my transaction, making it use that local copy instead of the global one, the middleware DOES fire.**

ie:

```
export const relayBBNToGraphcool = async () => {
    /* BEGIN without this code, WHICH IS ALREADY in the instantiation of apolloClient, the result is `user: null` */
    const authLink = setContext(async (req, { headers }) => {
        // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
        let getToken = async () => await AsyncStorage.getItem(/*'access_token'*/'graphcool_token')
        const token =  await getToken()

        console.trace('token for connection to graphcool is currently', token, req.operationName)

        // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
        return token
            ? {
                headers: {
                ...headers,
                authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
                }
            }
            : { headers }
    })

    const httpLink = new HttpLink(config)
    const link = ApolloLink.from([/* retryLink, */ authLink, httpLink])

    const cache = new InMemoryCache()
    // overriding apolloClient in the global scope of this module
    const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
        link,
        cache
    })
    /* END */    

    apolloClient.query({ query: User.self, forceFetch: true })
        .then(authneticatedUser => {
            console.trace('response', authneticatedUser)

            if(authneticatedUser.data.user === null)
                throw ('no user')
```

apolloClient is configured from *apollo-client* not *apollo-boost*. It is attached to its provider in App.js:

```
return (
  <ApolloProvider client={this.state.apolloClient}>
```

that is loaded from a different file with getApolloClient() -- which sets a local variable *apolloClient*:

```
var apolloClient //...
export const getApolloClient = () => { // ...
    apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
        link,
        cache
    }) //...
    return apolloClient
```

all calls to *.query* or *.mutate* are done from exported functions in this same file, and they use that same *var apolloClient*. I do not ever instantiate more than one apollo-client. Why is it that some of my queries are firing the middleware, but others are not ?

### edit:

per request, the actual links used:

```
// from src: https://github.com/kadikraman/offline-first-mobile-example/blob/master/app/src/config/getApolloClient.js
export const getApolloClient = async () => {
    const retryLink = new RetryLink({
        delay: {
            initial: 1000
        },
        attempts: {
            max: 1000,
            retryIf: (error, _operation) => {
                if (error.message === 'Network request failed') {
                    //if (_operation.operationName === 'createPost') 
                    //    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }
    })

    // from: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html
    const authLink = setContext(async (req, { headers }) => {
        // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
        let getToken = async () => await AsyncStorage.getItem(/*'access_token'*/'graphcool_token')
        const token =  await getToken()

        console.trace('token for connection to graphcool is currently', token, req.operationName)

        // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
        return token
            ? {
                headers: {
                ...headers,
                authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
                }
            }
            : { headers }
    })

    const httpLink = new HttpLink(config)
    const link = ApolloLink.from([retryLink, authLink, httpLink])

    const cache = new InMemoryCache()

    apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
        link,
        cache
    })

    try {
        await persistCache({
        cache,
        storage: AsyncStorage
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error restoring Apollo cache', err) // eslint-disable-line no-console
    }

    return apolloClient
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code for the actual links you are using, including your custom ones.

Comment: @DanielRearden okay, I've included the client initialization with all links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem has something to do with cache -- this section in the *getApolloClient* method:

```
try {
    await persistCache({
    cache,
    storage: AsyncStorage
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error restoring Apollo cache', err) // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

It works if I change the code to save apolloClient before that change is applied to the copy sent to ApolloProvider, like this:

```
export var apolloClient

// from src: https://github.com/kadikraman/offline-first-mobile-example/blob/master/app/src/config/getApolloClient.js
export const getApolloClient = async () => {
    apolloClient = await getRawClient()
    try {
        await persistCache({
        cache,
        storage: AsyncStorage
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error restoring Apollo cache', err) // eslint-disable-line no-console
    }

    return apolloClient
}

export const getRawClient = async () => {
    const retryLink = new RetryLink({
        delay: {
            initial: 1000
        },
        attempts: {
            max: 1000,
            retryIf: (error, _operation) => {
                if (error.message === 'Network request failed') {
                    //if (_operation.operationName === 'createPost') 
                    //    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }
    })

    // from: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html
    const authLink = setContext(async (req, { headers }) => {
        // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
        let getToken = async () => await AsyncStorage.getItem(/*'access_token'*/'graphcool_token')
        const token =  await getToken()

        console.trace('token for connection to graphcool is currently', token, req.operationName)

        // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
        return token
            ? {
                headers: {
                ...headers,
                authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
                }
            }
            : { headers }
    })

    const httpLink = new HttpLink(config)
    const link = ApolloLink.from([/* retryLink, */ authLink, httpLink])

    const cache = new InMemoryCache()

    return new ApolloClient({
        link,
        cache
    })
}
```

Then, I also refactor the query & mutate code out of this file, importing apolloClient. *That* works... which is kinda bizarre, but whatever.